# how to configure Surfraw on OSX?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

Has anyone had success configuring Surfraw on OSX? How do I get a working configuration for OSX? http://www.surfraw.org/

Comment: surfraw 2.2.8 is in both macports and homebrew - have you tried installing via those systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've installed it (I used Macports) your `~/.surfraw.conf` file should look like this, at a minimum:

```
SURFRAW_graphical=yes
SURFRAW_graphical_browser=open
```

The `open` command opens the default GUI application for whatever it's passed. In this case it's passed a http:// URL so it opens it in the default browser.

Comment: It needed the extra line `SURFRAW_text_browser=open`

Comment: Do you have `SURFRAW_text=yes` somewhere in there? Mine works great with ony those two lines. Anyway, glad you got it running!

Comment: It's strange, right? I did not have `SURFRAW_text=yes`. Don't know why `SURFRAW_graphical=yes` didn't work. Anyway, yes it's working, and thanks for the lead with `open`!

Answer (score 1):

[Surfraw 2.2.8](http://www.surfraw.org/) can be installed using either [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) or [Macports](http://www.macports.org).

Here's how to install via Homebrew. These commands should be typed within the terminal application:

**Install Homebrew**

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

**Install Surfraw**

```
brew install surfraw
```

Comment: It's installed, but when I run it, I get `/usr/local/bin/surfraw: line 470: /Applications/Google: No such file or directory`. I'm trying to figure out a working configuration. I don't have Lynx, so in my `.surfraw.conf` I'm using `SURFRAW_text_browser=/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`, which should be the correct file location.

Comment: How did you install? I used the above procedure, and when typing `$ sr google "foo"` it opens my default browser (Safari or Chrome). This is with no `.surfraw.conf` file

Comment: I installed using brew. I just deleted `.surfraw.conf`, uninstalling, then reinstalling using `brew install surfraw`. Then the command again. Same result: `/usr/local/bin/surfraw: line 470: http://www.google.com/search?q=foo&num=30: No such file or directory`

Comment: Tried installing with port. Same error, different directory: `/opt/local/bin/surfraw: line 470: http://www.google.com/search?q=foo&num=30: No such file or directory`

Comment: I made some progress. I tried `sr -browser="/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari" google foo`. But this opens Safari with the url `file:///Users/peter/http:/www.google.com/search%3Fq=foo&num=30`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working now. The config file needed the extra line `SURFRAW_text_browser=open`